# how to force Jetty to recompile jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty, subsonic

I'm running subsonic-5.2.1 media server on ubuntu 14.04.2 server which utilizes Jetty (not sure the version). I added a custom jsp file to the project called jtest.jsp and then modified the web.xml file so it would run as as servlet and it looks like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jtest</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/wap/jtest.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
        <param-vale>1</param-vale>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jtest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/kw.get</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm able to run it by going to mysite/kw.get , however when I edit the jsp file it still displays the same thing. I believe this is because it's not being recompiled. I tried adding in the checkInterval parameter which doesn't work, I have deleted the cache  in

```
/var/subsonic/jetty/4428/jsp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp
```

and have restarted the subsonic service (which restarts the jetty server) multiple times but it still shows my original code output.

I'm stuck pretty bad and help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Erm .....

```
     <param-vale>1</param-vale>
```

What is a "vale"?

I think you mean

```
     <param-value>1</param-value>
```

Comment: this is a good catch, however after changing to value I still have the same problem